# Frequencies for Hermitian Fourier Transform (`numpy.fft.hfft()`)? (hypothetical function `numpy.fft.hfftfreq()`)

Tags: python, numpy, fft

For a normal FFT, Numpy implements the method `fftfreq(n,d)`, which provides the frequencies of the FFT right away. However, for the Hermitian transformation `hfft`, the companion function `hfftfreq` is missing. What would be the returned values of the function `hfftfreq(n,d)`, if it existed?

Sources:

`numpy.fft.fftfreq`:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html

`Discrete Fourier Transform (numpy.fft)`:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html

Comment: This looks more like a question for the math stack.  Trying to parse hermitian transforms makes my eyes water.

Comment: Yes, maybe the question can be moved to the math stack. Anyhow, we already have a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hfft()` / `ihfft()` pairs are equivalent to `irfft()` / `rfft()` pairs, respectively and except for the normalization.

In particular, `np.fft.hfft(arr, n, norm='forward')` is identical to `np.fft.irfft(arr, n, norm='backward')` (the `backward` norm is the default).

```py
import numpy as np


n = 3
k = 2 * (n - 1)
s = np.arange(n)
print(s.astype(np.complex_))
# [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 2.+0.j]

irft_s = np.fft.irfft(s, k)
print(irft_s)
# [ 1.  -0.5  0.  -0.5]
print(np.fft.irfft(s, k, norm='forward'))
# [ 4. -2.  0. -2.]

hft_s = np.fft.hfft(s, k)
print(hft_s)
# [ 4. -2.  0. -2.]
print(np.fft.hfft(s, k, norm='forward'))
# [ 1.  -0.5  0.  -0.5]
print(hft_s / k)
# [ 1.  -0.5  0.  -0.5]
```

```py
# : get back to the original signal via the respective inverses
rr_s = np.fft.rfft(irft_s)
hh_s = np.fft.ihfft(hft_s)
print(rr_s, np.allclose(s, rr_s))
# [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 2.+0.j] True
print(hh_s, np.allclose(s, hh_s))
# [0.-0.j 1.-0.j 2.-0.j] True
```

```py
# : get back to the original signal via the mixed inverses
hr_s = np.fft.rfft(hft_s, norm='forward')
rh_s = np.fft.ihfft(irft_s, norm='forward')
print(hr_s, np.allclose(s, hr_s))
# [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 2.+0.j] True
print(rh_s, np.allclose(s, rh_s))
# [0.-0.j 1.-0.j 2.-0.j] True
```

Hence, the frequencies associated with the result of `hfft()` are actually the "frequencies" associated with the result of `irfft()`.
However, the "frequencies" associated to the inverse transform of the signal are the "time" of the samples of the signal, which are the natural numbers from `0` to `n - 1` (`n` being the size of the signal):

```py
np.arange(n)
```

Note that the samples of `ifft()` and `irfft()` (and `hfft()`) are the same.

Conversely, the samples associated with the result of `ihfft()` are given by `np.fft.rfftfreq()`.